# 503 Response Error Code - Using Graph API For Indexing Data against Microsoft Search

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have no clue as to why this is happening for this API only. I am getting **503 service unavailable**. Can someone please help me in this.
[image]

Payload Used:

```
{
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.externalItem",
  "acl": [
    {
      "type": "user",
      "value": "****Azure Object ID***",
      "accessType": "grant",
      "identitySource": "azureActiveDirectory"
    },
    {
      "type": "user",
      "value": "*****AZURE OBJECT ID******",
      "accessType": "grant",
      "identitySource": "azureActiveDirectory"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "Product": "Product created in manual",
    "Company": "ITC Infotech",
    "Category": "Mobile",
    "Description" : "this is just a dummy description",
    "Price": "$20.22",
    "HomePage": "https://www.google.com",
    "Image": "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gardenia-royalty-free-image-1580854928.jpg?crop=1xw:1xh;center,top&resize=480:*"
  },
  "content": {
    "value": "this is just a dummy description",
    "type": "text"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the document which you are using? This error arises sometimes due to the payload as well. Also try with PATCH.

Comment: Looks like you need to add `/external/connections` I believe. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/externalitem-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request

Comment: Oh my god.. I am so embarrassed. Cannot thank you enough I have spend 3-4 hours in this. Many thanks for your quick suggestion.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you.  Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `/external/`connections. Please look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/externalitem-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#http-request).